# Executing a remote shell script with prompts using cURL works on bash but not on zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

This command works perfectly fine when executed on bash.

```
sh < (curl -sSL https://myurl.com/install.sh)
```

It's an install script with some prompts that require y or n answers. Finally it installs a couple of programs, creates a directory, downloads some file and runs some nodejs program.

However, when running on zsh on Ubuntu it spits out:

```
zsh: number expected
```

What would be the correct syntax to run this script on zsh, be able to answer the questions inside the script and let it do its thing?

Comment: try running the cmd with shell debug/trace enabled and if it's not obvious what the problem is then  edit your question to show the minimal amount of code that generates the same error message. I mean `sh -vx <(curl ....)` (If you don't get a change in behavior with that then you'll have to add `set -vx` near the top o the script (after you download it as a file to your local machine) ) . Good luck!

Comment: just a small note, already pointed corrected by shellter, but your command appears to be trying to do process substitution, which should be done like `sh <(curl ...)` without a space before the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @shellter and @zaidhaan-hussain, the problem was my wrong syntax.

The code should be

```
sh <(curl -sSL https://myurl.com/install.sh)
```

without space between the `<` and `(`. That's the correct syntax for process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do:

```bash
$ bash < (curl -sSL https://myurl.com/install.sh)
```

Comment: I did. I got the same response.